# DB update script skips rows to update if I use multithreading

Tags: sql, ruby, database, multithreading, postgresql

I have a table that has about 40 million rows (about 120 million IDs) and I need to update some of the rows using a script that I wrote in Ruby. My DB is a PostgreSQL DB.

The problem that I'm having is that if I write a single threaded script, it runs very very slow (since it has to update each row separately, and there is time lost in opening and closing the connection). On the positive side, it successfully updates all the rows.

So to speed it up, I thought I'd write a multithreaded script so that I could utilize multiple connections. But the problem now is that some of the rows are just not updated without telling me why (my script has exception handling).

Here is my script that uses multithreading.

```
require 'sequel'
require 'logger'
......

DB = Sequel.connect('DB Credentials') # max connections = 20


starting_id = 1
total_objects = 120061827

queue = Queue.new
Thread.abort_on_exception = true

collector = Thread.new {
    (starting_id..total_objects).step(100000) do |id|
        lower_limit = id
        upper_limit = id + 100000
        if upper_limit > total_objects
            upper_limit = total_objects + 1
        end

        objects = DB["
            SELECT id, extra_fields
            FROM table
            WHERE json_typeof(extra_fields->'field') = 'object'
            AND id >= #{lower_limit}
            AND id < #{upper_limit}
        "]

        while queue.length >= 100
            progress_logger.info("Queue length limit reached. Sleeping Collector")
            sleep(5)
        end

        queue.push(objects)
        progress_logger.info("Pushing to Queue. FROM: #{lower_limit} TO: #{upper_limit}")
    end
    Thread.exit
}

def update_extra_fields(object, extra_fields, updater_logger, error_logger)
    begin
        update_query = DB["
            UPDATE table
            SET extra_fields = '#{JSON.generate(extra_fields)}'
            WHERE id = #{object[:id]}
        "]

        update_result = update_query.update
        updater_logger.info("Updated Photo ID: #{object[:id]}") if update_result == 1
    rescue Sequel::Error => e
        error_logger.info("Could not update 'extra_fields' for #{object[:id]} because #{e.message}")
    end
end

def construct_new_tags(tags)
    #logic
    return new_tags
end

def update_objects(objects, updater_logger, error_logger)
    objects.each do |object|
        extra_fields = JSON.parse(object[:extra_fields])
        tags = extra_fields["field"]
        new_tags = construct_new_tags(tags)
        extra_fields["new_field"] = new_tags
        update_extra_fields(object, extra_fields, updater_logger, error_logger)
    end
end

num_threads = 0
all_threads = []
consumer = Thread.new {
    while queue.length > 0
        if num_threads <= 15
            objects_block = queue.shift

            all_threads << Thread.new {
                num_threads += 1
                update_objects(objects_block, updater_logger, error_logger)
                num_threads -= 1
            }
        else
            progress_logger.info("Threads limit reached. Sleeping Updater")
            sleep(1)
        end
    end
}

collector.join
consumer.join    
all_threads.each do |thread|
    thread.join
end


puts "Queue END reached: EXIT"
```

1. Nothing ever gets logged in the error_logger
2. The number of rows updated each time I run the script is different. So I'm confident that there isn't a specific pattern that I'm missing rows to update etc.
3. If I write a single threaded script that follows the same logic. All the rows are successfully updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in your collector.

When the queue length is larger than 100 you are simply throwing your data away and `queue.push(photos)` should be `queue.push(objects)`.

```
        if queue.length >= 100
            progress_logger.info("Queue length limit reached. Sleeping Collector")
            sleep(5)
        else
            queue.push(photos)
            progress_logger.info("Pushing to Queue. FROM: #{lower_limit} TO: #{upper_limit}")
        end
```

You probably want something like this:

```
queue = Queue.new
...
        while queue.length >= 100
            progress_logger.info("Queue length limit reached. Sleeping Collector")
            sleep(5)
        end

        queue.push(objects)
        progress_logger.info("Pushing to Queue. FROM: #{lower_limit} TO: #{upper_limit}")

...

all_threads = []

consumer = Thread.new {
  loop {
  if num_threads <= 15
    objects_block = queue.shift

    all_threads << Thread.new {
      num_threads += 1
      update_objects(objects_block, updater_logger, error_logger)
      num_threads -= 1
    }
  else
    progress_logger.info("Threads limit reached. Sleeping Updater")
    sleep(1)
  end
  }
}

collector.join

while !queue.empty?
  sleep(10)
end

all_threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
end
```

Comment: Oh! Great catch! "objects" should be "photos" because, well "objects" isn't anything I just changed names to obfuscate the real names. But thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The second thing is that if queue is larger than 100 you do nothing with the `objects`.

Comment: So I updated my code with yours and I'm still seeing rows being skipped. I updated my original post too to reflect how my script looks now. I agree that I was missing a crucial piece in my code but still about 33% of the rows are being skipped

Comment: Use a real queue instead of a simple array, i update my answer.

Comment: Yes, just tried that. Still skipping. The results improved slightly though. Now skips about 28%. Thats a ~5% improvement.

Comment: add collector.join at the end.

Comment: Yes, just tried that too. Still skipping. Also I updated my script in the original answer to reflect exactly how it looks now

Comment: Join the consumer, too.

Comment: Yes just tried it with consumer and join. Still skipping and I get the error saying that each is not defined for type Queue on the all_threads.each line. I guess we'll have to use a simple array for that right?

Comment: since you are only accessing it within the consumer and after the consumer is finished an array is ok.

Comment: how much you are still missing?

Comment: Its been a ton of improvement actually. About 8% is still missing

Comment: the `while queue.length > 0` in the consumer is still a problem.

Comment: Why do you think that is the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: Holy Shit that worked! 100% rows getting updated! You're an absolute multithreading beast! Can I endorse you in LinkedIn or something? lol

Comment: Also just for my knowledge'd sake can you explain why `while queue.length > 0` was a problem? I still don't understand

Comment: because the queue could become empty even though the collector is still adding new items to it, because the consumer is just faster than the collector.

Comment: makes sense. Anyways just wanted to say that you're help was like Godsend tonight. Much appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: one last question. Why did you remove `consumer.join` from your code? If I remove it, it skips rows. If I keep it gives me `No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)` on the line where I add it (I add it after `collector.join` and before `all_threads.each...`. Any ideas?

Comment: you stil have `while queue.length > 0` in your code, please update your code. Then i can look at it again.